# How to use Wildcards?

Tags: xml, powershell, wildcard

I have XML that inserts the local hostname. The hostname could be any of the below:

```xml
<name>lonmq1111</name>
<name>stoms1111</name>
<name>bqqlk1111</name>
<name>hkgtp1111</name>
```

Dependent on the name of the host the script below needs to add the correct gateways to the XML. For example:

```
IF <name>lon*<name> OR <name>sto*<name> THEN
    add these gateways
ELSEIF <name>bqq*</name> OR <name>hkg*</name> THEN
    add different gateways
ELSEIF etc.
```

I have the below, but it is not working. Any ideas on how to use wildcards in the middle?

```bsh
$file = Get-Content C:\testnew.xml
if ($file -like ' <name>lon*</name>' -or '<name>sto*</name>') {
  # load XML file
  [xml]$doc = Get-Content "C:\testnew.xml"

  # create node <hostname>
  $comp = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'hostname', '')
  $desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('test')
  $comp.AppendChild($desc)

  # create node <port>
  $sref = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'port', '')
  $desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('1111')
  $sref.AppendChild($desc)

  # create node <gateway> and append child nodes <hostname> and <port>
  $src = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'gateway', '')
  $src.AppendChild($comp)
  $src.AppendChild($sref)

  # append node <gateway> to node <gateways>
  $svc = $doc.SelectSingleNode('//gateways')
  $svc.AppendChild($src)

  # create node <hostname>
  $comp = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'hostname', '')
  $desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('test2')
  $comp.AppendChild($desc)

  # create node <port>
  $sref = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'port', '')
  $desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('2222')
  $sref.AppendChild($desc)

  # create node <gateway> and append child nodes <hostname> and <port>
  $src = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'gateway', '')
  $src.AppendChild($comp)
  $src.AppendChild($sref)

  # append node <Source> to node <Service>
  $svc = $doc.SelectSingleNode('//gateways')
  $svc.AppendChild($src)

  # save XML file
  $doc.Save("C:\testnew.xml")
}
```

I could just use `*lon*` and remove the `<name>` but everything else in the XML is auto populated. I could end up in the scenario where `*bqq*` and `*lon*` be in the document which I want to avoid. Note - this must work on powershell v2.0.

The XML that will be edited:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<netprobe compatibility="1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.itrsgroup.com/GA2011.2-110303/netprobe.xsd">
  <selfAnnounce>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <retryInterval>60</retryInterval>
    <requireReverseConnection>false</requireReverseConnection>
    <probeName>
      <hostname />
      <data>_</data>
      <port />
      <data>-SA</data>
    </probeName>
    <managedEntity>
      <name>lonms1122</name>
      <attributes>
      </attributes>
      <types>
      </types>
    </managedEntity>
    <gateways>
      <gateway>
      </gateway>
    </gateways>
  </selfAnnounce>
</netprobe>
```

@Mathias

Your answer works great. See the code below

```
$doc = [xml](Get-Content C:\selfannouncetestnew.xml)

$gateway = switch -Wildcard($doc.SelectSingleNode('//managedEntity/name').InnerText)
{
    "lon*" {
# create node <hostname>
$comp = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'hostname', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('test')
$comp.AppendChild($desc)

# create node <port>
$sref = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'port', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('1111')
$sref.AppendChild($desc)

# create node <gateway> and append child nodes <hostname> and <port>
$src = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'gateway', '')
$src.AppendChild($comp)
$src.AppendChild($sref)

# append node <gateway> to node <gateways>
$svc = $doc.SelectSingleNode('//gateways')
$svc.AppendChild($src)

# create node <hostname>
$comp = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'hostname', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('test2')
$comp.AppendChild($desc)

# create node <port>
$sref = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'port', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('2222')
$sref.AppendChild($desc)

# create node <gateway> and append child nodes <hostname> and <port>
$src = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'gateway', '')
$src.AppendChild($comp)
$src.AppendChild($sref)

# append node <gateway> to node <gateways>
$svc = $doc.SelectSingleNode('//gateways')
$svc.AppendChild($src)

$doc.Save("c:\selfannouncetestnew.xml")

    }

    "sto*" {
   # create node <hostname>
$comp = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'hostname', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('test3')
$comp.AppendChild($desc)

# create node <port>
$sref = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'port', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('3333')
$sref.AppendChild($desc)

# create node <gateway> and append child nodes <hostname> and <port>
$src = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'gateway', '')
$src.AppendChild($comp)
$src.AppendChild($sref)

# append node <gateway> to node <gateways>
$svc = $doc.SelectSingleNode('//gateways')
$svc.AppendChild($src)

# create node <hostname>
$comp = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'hostname', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('test4')
$comp.AppendChild($desc)

# create node <port>
$sref = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'port', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('4444')
$sref.AppendChild($desc)

# create node <gateway> and append child nodes <hostname> and <port>
$src = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'gateway', '')
$src.AppendChild($comp)
$src.AppendChild($sref)

# append node <gateway> to node <gateways>
$svc = $doc.SelectSingleNode('//gateways')
$svc.AppendChild($src)

$doc.Save("c:\selfannouncetestnew.xml")    

    }

    "bqq*" {
        "barragw:3456"
    }

    "hkg*" {
        "hongkonggw:4567"
    }

    default {
        "defaultgw:5678"
    }
}

$hostname,$port = $gateway -split ':'
# create node <hostname>
$comp = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'hostname', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode($hostname)
$comp.AppendChild($desc)

# create node <port>
$sref = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'port', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode($port)
$sref.AppendChild($desc)


$doc.Save("C:\selfannouncetestnew.xml")
```

To test the bottom part of your answer, i changed the name to `hkggk1122` but nothing happens. If the name is `lon(something)` or `sto(something)` it adds the gateways. I want to get your solution to work but not sure what you are trying to tell me do with the bottom part.

Comment: You'd probably be better off parsing the existing xml and using XPath to find name-nodes with the relevant values. Can you show us (a sample of) the entire xml document structure?

Comment: @Mathias, see the update. I have included the XML, everything in here gets auto populated dependent on which host it is.

Comment: Just as a side note: `$var -like 'A' -or 'B'` doesn't work as you seem to expect. The logic in the expression works like this: `($var -like 'A') -or ('B')`. `'B'` is a non-empty string, so it evaluates to `$true` in a boolean operation. And since boolean OR operations evaluate to true if one of their clauses is true your whole expression is always `$true`. You need to compare the variable to each string individually to get the result you want: `$var -like 'A' -or $var -like 'B'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the entire document up front, find the `managementEntity/name` node and use a `switch` to decide on the gateway details:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\testnew.xml)

$gateway = switch -Wildcard($xml.SelectSingleNode('//managedEntity/name').InnerText)
{
    "lon*" {
        "londongw:1234"
    }

    "sto*" {
        "stockholmgw:2345"
    }

    "bqq*" {
        "barragw:3456"
    }

    "hkg*" {
        "hongkonggw:4567"
    }

    default {
        "defaultgw:5678"
    }
}

$hostname,$port = $gateway -split ':'

# Create appropriate childnodes and append here
# create node <hostname>
$comp = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'hostname', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode($hostname)
$comp.AppendChild($desc)

# create node <port>
$sref = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'port', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode($port)
$sref.AppendChild($desc)

# and so on ...
```

Comment: I have been trying to figure out how to use switch and use it in my scenario. Your example has helped, thank you. But I still don't quite get how switch works. if the name was lon* something then does it carry out everything inside the {}? And what is the last line for?

Comment: Yes, if the text inside the `name` node is `-like lon*`, the code inside the following `{}` will be executed, so `$gateway` ends up having `"londongw:1234"` assigned to it. The `default` block executes if no matches are found. If you are absolutely sure that only the 4 listed options exist, you can remove the `default` block

Comment: OK, and what does `$hostname,$port = $gateway -split ':'` do?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? :)

Comment: The script is working great if i put my code to create the elements inside the switch. I tested the bottom code with and without but nothing happens. What are you expecting to put for `# Create appropriate childnodes and append here`?

Comment: @DineshK I would probably do *just* the hostname/port pair assignments inside the switch - the creation of the xml nodes is the same in any case, no need to duplicate that code

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your `like` parameter. Replace

```
' <name>lon*</name>'
```

with:

```
'<name>lon*</name>'
```

Comment: well noticed. However that didn't make a difference. script keeps adding the gateways still.